# Menu variable not in scope Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, scope, let, do-notation

I am trying to create a menu which read the data from a textfile. But I get three errors that variable not in scope despite having at the start of the IO(). Am I not reading the txt.file properly and is the way I creating the menu wrong?

errors

```
Variable not in scope: spaDatabase :: [Spa]

--line of error for spaDatabase
let updatedDB = (addSpa rid br ar (read st) spaDatabase)

Variable not in scope: spaDB
Variable not in scope: updatedDB :: [Spa]

--line of error for updatedDB
2 -> putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB) >> menu spaDB
```

My code

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
       contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
       let spaDatabase = (read contents :: [Spa])
       menu spaDatabase
       putStrLn "" 
     where  menu spaDatabase = do
                putStrLn "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" 
                putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "       
                putStrLn "2: Show all spa "   
                putStr "\nSelected option: "
                putStrLn ""
                option <- getLine    
                putStrLn "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
                
            output :: Int -> IO ()
            output option = do 
                case option of 1 -> do putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
                                       rid <- getLine
                                       putStrLn "Enter Spa Brand Name: "
                                       br <- getLine
                                       putStrLn "Enter Spa Area: "
                                       ar <- getLine
                                       putStrLn "Enter Spa Stars: "
                                       st <- getLine
                                       let updatedDB = (addSpa rid br ar (read st) spaDatabase)
                                       putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB)
                                       writeFile "spa.txt" (spaListStr updatedDB)

                        
                               2 -> putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB) >> menu spaDB
```

Comment: In the where of the `main` function you define two functions `menu` and `output`. These function do not inherite the scope of the `do` block. Now since `output` has no parameter named `spaDatabase` and no variable higher in the scope exists you get the error.

Comment: I would suggest to avoid `do .. where`. The variables you bind inside the `do` are not visible inside `where`. If you only use `let` inside `do` instead you don't have this issue.

Comment: Thank you chi! Although now I have a parse error menu spaDatabase = do, is that due to indentation?

Comment: edits should not invalidate existing answers. I rolled back. If you have new question to ask with a new code, you're welcome to post a new question, stating it's a followup to this one, including the link to it if you feel it's relevant. :)

Comment: Thank you Will! I manage to clear the top part error but it become a parse error at the second choice. I will add the link from this one to that one.

Answer (score 1):

`where` is part of a *definition*, not of *expression*. It  belongs to the `main`'s definition so its scope goes *above* `do`'s. Your originally posted code

```
main = do { .....
            let c = .....
            .....
          }
       where
          a = ....
          b = ....c....
          .....
```

is equivalent to

```
main = let {       -- where's translation
          a = ....
          b = ....c....
          .....
          }
       in
          do {
               .....
               let c = .....
               .....
             }
```

You're using `c` in `b = ....c....` *before* it is introduced with `let c = .....`, i.e. *outside* of its scope region. That's an error, *"variable not in scope"*.

*update*. `let` in `do` blocks is just a shortcut:

```
              do {
                   .....
                   let c = .....
                   .....
                 }
```

is the same as

```
              do {
                   .....
                   let c = .....
                   in do {
                           .....
                         }
                 }
```

The working code could be structured, as also [@chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi) proposed in the comments, as

```
main = do { .....
            let c = .....
            .....
            let { a = ....
                  b = ....c....
                }
            .....
         }
```

That way `a` and `b` are *in* `c`'s scope, so may use `c` as part of their definitions.

Comment: sorry but what is 'in'?

Comment: part of the `let` expression syntax in Haskell.

Comment: sorry, but I don't really understand your code. what does a, b, and c come from? Is there an indentation issue?

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters is a good introductory material. e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be explains `let`.

Comment: I have modified my code based on your model. Is this the way it should look? Although I have a parse error on 'in'?

Comment: a, b, and c is whatever  you have in their place. I've edited.